# How to compare a number in if condition?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I wrote this code for the user to guess a password exactly 4 times but I am not able to compare the input with the pin, is the way I have compared here wrong? can I not compare the number directly? like

```
if (input !== 0704)
```

is it wrong if I'm writing the number directly like this? it works fine if I replace the number with a string.

```
let pin = 0704;
let count = 0;
for (i=1; i<=4; i++) {
    let input = prompt('please make a guess');
    if (input !== 0704 ) {
        console.log('Sorry that was wrong');
        count++;
    }
    else {
        console.log('That was correct!')
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem with numbers is ... 1: leading zeros are not significant, and 2: that number, with a leading zero, and no digits above 7 actually equals 452 - why? hint ... `012` === `10`

Comment: Two things here: a PIN is text, not a number (you won't be doing maths and `704` should not be considered equal to `0704`). And `0704` in JavaScript is an octal literal that equals `452` in decimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if by input you are meaning html input then you need to compare the value with a string since output of html input is in string format. Also note the preceding 0 in 0704 will be ignored. So in this case you can use 0704 as string and perform comparison

```js
let pin = '0704';
let count = 0;
for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
  let input = prompt('please make a guess');
  if (input !== pin) {
    console.log('Sorry that was wrong');
    count++;
  } else {
    console.log('That was correct!')
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, I did read that output of HTML input is string format, I will do it with a string then, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

With number, input 0704 / 000704 has same value.
It must be a "String".